# Upper Limit Topology: Interior and Closure of $[0,1) \cup (2,3]$

Tags: general-topology

> Upper Limit Topology, Interior and Closure of $[0,1) \cup (2,3]$

I'm a bit confused on finding the interior, on one hand $(2,3]$ is a basis element in the upper limit topology, so by definition it's already open, however I'm having a hard time figuring out what the open subset of $[0,1)$ would be. Would it be $(0, 1-\epsilon]$ ? This seems rather informal, and I'm not quite sure if it's correct.

Similarly, I'm confused on finding the closure and don't know where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interior of $[0, 1)$ is the union of all intervals of the form $(0, 1-\varepsilon]$ for $\varepsilon > 0$.

The upper limit topology is strictly finer than the standard topology. So intervals that don't contain their end points are still open.

The closure of a set is the complement of the interior of the complement. So we want to find the interior of $(-\infty, 0)\cup [1, 2]\cup (3,\infty)$, which is $(-\infty, 0)\cup (1, 2]\cup (3, \infty)$. The complement of this is then
$$
[0, 1]\cup (2, 3]
$$

Comment: Hello @Arthur, if I follow your example for the set [$0,1$] ( with the upper limit topology ) if I want the interior of this set it's the union of all intervals of the form ($0,1-\epsilon$)?

Comment: @EmmaFlora Yes, although $(0,1-\varepsilon)$ isn't a base open set for the upper limit topology (although it is open). So using $(0,1-\varepsilon]$ is cleaner.

Comment: Oh I see we should always respect the basis of the topology we're using ?

Comment: @EmmaFlora It isn't necessary, at all. But as long as it doesn't cost anything, it is a bit easier to follow for anyone who reads it. If using non-base open sets makes anything easier or shorter, then that's probably the better option. But either way, it's mostly a matter of aesthetics.

Comment: Alright thank you, may I ask you one last question or should I post it ? Anyway here it is for the derived set (still using the upper limit topology)  of ($0,1$) for example should be ($0,1$] also ?

Answer (score 0):

For any $x>0$ in $[0,1)$, $(0,x]$ is open and a subset of $[0,1)$ so all $x \in (0,1)$ are interior points, and $0$ is not, because a basic neighbourhood of $0$ is $(x,0]$ with $x<0$ and this is never a subset of $[0,1)$ (witnessed by $\frac{x}{2}$). So $(0,1) \cup (2,3]$ is the interior.

The closure of $[0,1) \cup (2,3]$ only gets $1$ as a new point, as any neighbourhood of $1$ contains points $<1$ so from $[0,1)$, so $1$ is a limit (adherence) point of the set. $[0,1] \cup (2,3]$ is then the closure.